# Authenticate.aspx Page Looks Like Garbage

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, 2016

Why does SharePoint 2013 and 2016 Authenticate.aspx login page for FBA look like garbage compared to SharePoint 2010? It look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0BP3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer authentication page is simpler for two reasons I think:
1. It's easier to skin via CSS and to implement in a pop-up window, for a more integrated experience.
2. Organizations are expected to create/customize their own, so nothing special as done with the default.

Comment: Fair enough, but when migrating from SP 2010 to SP 2013/2016 and upon first glance, one would think that something went wrong. Look at the 2010 version, it looks clean and professional http://imgur.com/mkO99v0

Comment: :) I can see that.